# game development need help examples?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

i'm developing game in visual c++ can anyone give me links for developed games in visual c++ so i can download the sample games to study the structure of games

any useful readymade games in visual-c++ links useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Nehe's tutorials:

http://nehe.gamedev.net/

Answer (score 0):

Parallax released the source code for some of their old games a while back. These are **old** games from the mid to late 90's and they are missing proprietary drivers and data files. I am sure there are other examples online.

Descent [1](http://www.descent2.com/ddn/sources/descent1/) [2](http://www.descent2.com/ddn/sources/descent2/)

FreeSpace [2](http://www.hard-light.net/wiki/index.php/Getting_the_FreeSpace2%3a_SCP_Source_Code)